# How to define a list of known Java Bean Validation constraint annotations?

Tags: java, list, annotations, constraints

I'm getting the error below when trying to define a list of Java Bean Validation constraint annotations inside a List, how should this be defined?

```
Expression expected
```

```java
public final List<Constraint> TEXT_CONSTRAINTS = Arrays.asList(
    javax.validation.constraints.NotNull
);
```

Comment: NotNull is a constraint, the "array" (just presuming) is  "javax.validation.constraints"